# Can I create a linked server in sql server 2005 whose target is sql server 2000 (sp3 )?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, linked-server

Is it possible to create a linked server in SQL Server 2005, which links to a SQL Server 2000 SP3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Check the link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)